# Python re.sub (Simple but yet stuck)

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to read this string and convert it to a list using re.sub, yet havent succeeded yet don't know why.

```
STRING: [Nick('LeaderBot'), 'd3rdwill', 'Willie2']

Expected Outcome: ['LeaderBot', 'd3rdwill', 'Willie2']
```

The function I'm using is this:

```
def str2list(str2):
'''
Converts a string to a list
:param str2:
:return:
'''
lst = re.sub("\(\[\]\)", '', str2).replace("'", "").strip("()").split(',')
return lst
```

and I'm calling it like this to remove Nick( that is not a general sting to list request in my code:

```
    orderGroupNick = str2list(STRING.replace("Nick(", ""))
```

the result I'm having is this:

```
['[LeaderBot)', ' d3rdwill', ' Willie2]']
```

I've changed the regex lots of times to include ' or some other formats of [ and ( but not yet successful to have a clean list in the end.

I know it's a simple thing to do, not sure why I'm stuck here!

Answer (score 4):

You're using `split(',')` on a string that looks like `[one, two, three]`... the `[` and `]` here aren't scrapped, nor is the whitespace after the comma '`,`'.

Instead use `split(", ")` after you scrap the `[` in front and `]` in the end.

Comment: You can get rid of the brackets with `lst = str2[1:-1].split(',')`

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight As seen from OP his own answer posted, he used `.strip("[]")`. However yours would work better, but assumes a non-empty string.

Answer (score 2):

In the below, just convert the `re.sub` command output to a list.

```
>>> str
"[Nick('LeaderBot'), 'd3rdwill', 'Willie2']"
>>> re.sub(r'.*\((?=\')|(?<=\')\)?,?\s?]?', r'', str)
"'LeaderBot''d3rdwill''Willie2'"
```

The above regex matches  all the characters execpt the characters within single quotes plus the single quotes. `re.sub` command removes all the matched characters.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8eK5/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findall` function for a cleaner solution:

```
regex = re.compile("\'(.+?)\'")
lst = regex.findall(str2)
```

And you should get a list like this `[u'LeaderBot', u'd3rdwill', u'Willie2']`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the easy way to do it:

```
subject = "[Nick('LeaderBot'), 'd3rdwill', 'Willie2']"
regex = re.compile(r"'([^']+)'")
print( re.findall(regex, subject) )
```

Output: `['LeaderBot', 'd3rdwill', 'Willie2']`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Unihedron,

Finally this worked:

```
    lst = re.sub("[()]", '', str2).replace("'", "").strip("[]").split(', ')
```